# method to check if user input formatted correctly

Tags: java

I'm writing this method to check for different kinds of bad user input. I have been writing a BigInt class and I need to make sure there is nothing like "++2", "--2", letters, number split by spaces such as "222 333", or periods. I've never uses a String splitter before, and I'm not getting the expected tokenCount. For example, if I enter "++2" into the console tokenCount=1, but I had thought I would get 3.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
public static boolean checkValidInput(String val) {
    String input = val;
    String[] delims = {"//+", "-", "a", " ", "."};
    String[] tokens;
    int tokenCount;
    boolean validInput = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < delims.length; i++) {
        tokens = input.split(delims[i]);
        tokenCount = tokens.length;
        if(delims[i].equals("//+")){
            if(tokenCount > 2){
                validInput = true;
            } else {
                validInput = false;
            }
        } else if(delims[i].equals("-")){
            if(tokenCount > 2){
                validInput = true;
            } else {
                validInput = false;
            }
        } else if(delims[i].equals("a")){
            if(tokenCount > 1){
                validInput = true;
            } else {
                validInput = false;
            }
        } else if(delims[i].equals(" ")){
            if(tokenCount > 1){
                validInput = true;
            } else {
                validInput = false;
            }
        } else if(delims[i].equals(".")){
            if(tokenCount > 1){
                validInput = true;
            } else {
                validInput = false;
            }
        } 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a count of `1` because you are incorrectly escaping the special character `+` (in *regex* it has a special meaning). It should be escaped with `\\`:

```
String[] delims = {"\\+", "-", "a", " ", "."};
```

**Notice** that the method `split(String)` expects a *regex* as argument.

Answer (score 0):

try regex

```
input.matches("[+-]?\\d+");
```